# Excel VBA - Loop to Compare Cells, Offset entire row

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, loopback, conditional-statements

Hopefully someone can help me with this!

Just started learning VBA.

I am trying the following code.

The aim is to compare cells in rows starting from row 4 to and offset entire row up or down based on conditions

Conditions are

Start Date must be between Not Before and Not After dates
Age must be greater or equal to 11

```
Sub sequenceOptimizer()   

'Processing Start Date: Column E - Column Number: 5
'Processing Not Before: Column K - Column Number: 11
'Processing Not After: Column L - Column Number: 12
'Processing Age at Processing Start Date: Column M - Column Number: 13   

Dim rw As Long

With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For rw = 2 To LastRow    

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        If .Cells(rw, 5) < .Cells(rw, 11) Then 
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If .Cells(rw, 5) >= .Cells(rw, 11) And .Cells(rw, 13) < 11 Then 
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If .Cells(rw, 5) >= .Cells(rw, 11) And .Cells(rw, 5) <= .Cells(rw, 12) And .Cells(rw, 13) < 
            11 Then 
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If .Cells(rw, 5) >= .Cells(rw, 11) And .Cells(rw, 5) > .Cells(rw, 12) Then 
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Offset(-1, 0).Select

        End If
    Next Row   
    Loop

End With

End Sub
```

[image]

I created a flow diagram to illustrate the process.

Instead of using LastRow, the last row can be set to Row Number 3001 since maximum number of batches is 3000.

Firstly, the spreadsheet was sorted using simple Excel Multiple Levels Sorting in the beginning by Not Before date, then by Not After date and lastly by Grow start date and then formula was inserted for calculated columns.

In ideal conditions, this simple sorting without using VBA macro should have given the ideal sequence.

However, in the previous year the Not Before and Not After dates criteria was not respected to process the Batches.

Therefore, when same Not Before and Not After time periods are applied in current year, Age in the following year (which is difference between Processing Start Date in current year and Grow Start date (equal to Processing Start date in previous year) are less than 11 months for some batches.

Then comes in the VBA macro to find the ideal sequence by starting processing with Row Number 4 and moving to the next row simply in ascending Row Number up to the last non blank row.

In the end, the macro ensures the Processing start date is always between Not Before and Not After dates with Age greater or equal to 11.

On event, the criteria Age >= 11 cannot be satisfied by keeping Processing start date between Not Before and Not After dates, the row is moved upwards until Processing start date is between Not Before and Not After dates. In other words, Best before date.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Is your code not working? You have not stated what is wrong with it. "The aim is to compare cells in rows starting from row 4", then why is the loop starting at row 2 (`For rw = 2 To LastRow `)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, the issue is the code is not working. Thanks for highlighting the error rw=2, it should have been 4. But still the code is not working after correction.

Comment: Canyou show what the results must be based on the first 5 rows? Are you trying to sort the rows?

Comment: The aim of the code is to sort the rows to be the best sequence.

Comment: The conditions are Start Date must be between Not Before and Not After dates and Age at Start date must be greater than or equal to 11. On event Start Date is smaller than the Not Before date, the row is moved down. On event Start date is greater than Not Before date but Age is less than 11, the row is moved down. On event, Start Date is between Not Before and Not After dates, but Age is less than 11 the row is moved down. This loop is stopped on event Start date exceeds Not After date and the row is returned to the previous position whereby the Start Date is smaller or equal to Not After.

Comment: Based on your image, the data seems to already be sorted. If not, edit your question and show the results for at least the first 5 rows.

Comment: The top rows are sorted, the problematic rows start as from row 50. Kindly find a sample spreadsheet on the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OkU6bYcRGNa3ZzNg5ROXIKzVu-2B5Vqc/view?usp=sharing